# Cannot find the ISO file on my computer

Tags: usb, iso

Your help greatly appreciated.

I have downloaded pendrivelinux USB installer and downloaded the Ubuntu ISO file which is 900 or so mbs...however when I browse from pendrivelinux USB installer I can only 'see' my MP3 files etc., ISO file doesn't appear. The browser says "iso file" i have tried to change it to 'all files' bit it doesn't, and I checked the ISO file to say 'unblock' but it still doesn't appear so I cannot select it.

I have looked on here and online for answers but no-one mentions this.

Hopefully someone here has an idea. I'm so excited to put this operating system on my notebook.

Thank you for your help, - Jamie

Comment: can you get a screen shot of pendrive linux and also show where is your iso file located

Comment: The whole 900MB+ file that has the mp3 files, etc. is the Ubuntu iso file. You can burn the iso file to a DVD or else use an application like Universal USB Installer to write the Ubuntu iso file to a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) instead of pendrivelinux.